# How to pass owner attribute when creating user story using Rally API?

Tags: rest, api, rally

I am trying to pass the owner attribute to create a user story in rally using rally API But I am encountering below error.

```
{
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors": [
            "Cannot parse object reference from \"{\"Owner\": {\"_refObjectName\": \"Ron\"}}\""
        ],
        "Warnings": [
            "Ignored JSON element HierarchicalRequirement.PortfolioItem during the processing of this request."
        ]
    }
```

}

My request payload

```
{
"HierarchicalRequirement":{
                "Name": "hello Wrold",
                "Description":" 123 test description",              
                "Workspace": "/workspace/18686460234",
                "Project":"/project/1025697468602323",
                "PortfolioItem":"",
                "Owner":{"_refObjectName":"Ron"},
                "ScheduleState":"Defined"
            }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when referring to an object property that itself is an object (as in this case with the User object), you pass in the actual value of _ref, not another object. If you have previously been passed the reference to the user as a full blown URI, then you can still pass that in and the SDK will convert it to a _ref.

If you go to the webservice docs (https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) for your subscription and go down to the User section, you can get the docs to fetch you some examples of users. The _ref will come back something like:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/39776836851

I believe that you can either use that, or just truncate it to the number at the end. So the code will need to be changed so that the Owner line reads:

"Owner" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/39776836851"